# How does ‘Transformers: Rescue Bots’ fit into the Aligned Continuity?

Tags: transformers

Supposedly, *Transformers: Rescue Bots* is part of [the Aligned Continuity](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Aligned_continuity_family).

I've only watched a few early episodes and read [the TF Wiki entry](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Transformers:_Rescue_Bots_%28cartoon%29), which states that the Rescue Bots are a rookie team which has been sent to live/train in a remote area (more remote than Jasper, NV?)

From what I've seen (feel free to correct me, I've only seen 2 or 3 episodes), the Rescue Bots don't seem to hide their robot natures much, unlike Team Prime who are under strict orders to remain in disguise as much as possible. Wikia mentions that Optimus and Bumblebee also help out the Rescue Bots from time to time.

From what I've seen in recent promos and toys, Optimus is not only still making appearances, but has also gained some sort of dinosaur alt-mode.

This is all sort of contradictory from *Transformers: Prime* in that not only has Optimus never had a dinosaur alt-mode, but as of right now,

> Optimus Prime is dead, and until the new *Transformers: Robots In Disguise*  begins, Bumblebee is still on Cybertron.

How, or when does *Transformers: Rescue Bots* match up with *Transformers: Prime* and the rest of the Aligned Continuity?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to Executive Producer Jeff Kline both *Transformers: Rescue Bots* and *Transformers: Prime* [are in continuity with each other](http://www.tfw2005.com/transformers-news/transformers-prime-39/steve-blum-and-jeff-kline-talk-rescue-bots-transformers-prime-174315/). Rescue Bots was purposely set in an island to avoid contact with the Prime characters.

So, canon wise, they are in the same continuity. However, in practice it's rather problematic given the differences between the two shows. That being said, being internally inconsistent is consistent with the Transformers franchise :D

**Addendum:**

I've also only seen a few episodes of Rescue Bots, but I suppose you *could* fit its events to be before the events of Prime. Would also explain the absence of Decepticons. It also introduces its own slew of problems (where were the Rescue Bots when Team Prime was fighting for its life and their home planet?), but that almost always happens when you look to deeply into TF fiction.

Answer (score 2):

It partially does, for instance, watch TFP Season 2 Episode 8 Nemesis Prime then watch Rescue Bots Season 2 Episodes 10 and 11 What Lies Below and What Rises Above. Optimus claimed he was away at subterranean Energon deposit and even pulled out a shard to prove it and around this time in Rescue Bots, Optimus Prime shows up to mine Energon with the Rescue Bots underground. He also got trapped underground with the Rescue Bots which would explain his "out of communication" statement.